# How to check uniqueness of Document's field across all collections?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have multiple collection in my MongoDB for ex. Principal, Hierarchy, Tenant, Application. I want to insert a document in Application but I have to check that "name" column is unique across all the collections in DB. What are the possible ways I can do it ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee for uniqueness across the collections.

You can use unique index feature on single collection. To ensure uniqueness across collections, you need to make a query and check for existence. If the field(s) with same value(s) exists, then skip the insert.

Comment: Could you please suggest me the syntax for the query to check for existence  across all collection because I found the query only for a particular collection ?

Comment: Yes, you need to fire multiple queries.

Comment: Do I need to check for each collection ?

Comment: Yes. That's the ideal way. Or you need to keep a meta collection which holds unique value for any field.